# Datatables - Drill down rows with nested independent table

Tags: datatables

Is anyone using DataTables with drill down rows and nested independent table? Similar to powerTable?

Can you post any links/examples?

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark the answer as such.

Comment: this is latest official sample - http://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02 @user1339164

Comment: There is [nested-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-datatables) for this purpose

Answer (score 30):

Here's my **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rafael_cichocki/WwDg8/7/)**(*press "Run" for icons to show*) which implements independent nested jQuery DataTables.
In this case I just copy the html of the original Table, and post it into the Details row, to save me the hassle of making a new Table.

Here's the only interesting part of the code really, that makes the NestedTables different from simple DrillDown:

```
else {      /* Open this row */

            this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";

            // fnFormatDetails() pieces my Table together, instead you can 
            // use whatever code you like to create your nested Table html
            oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details');

            // ... and here I cast dataTable() on the newly created nestedTable 
            oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });
            iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
        }
```

Notice how you can Filter, Sort, etc.. on each table independently.

Answer (score 21):

I built on top of Rafael Cichocki's excellent jsfiddle adding dynamic data and two different datatables to emphasize that the fact that detail table can be different from the master table:

http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/zz3cH/

```
$('#exampleTable tbody td img').live('click', function () {
            var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            var nTds = this;

            if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                /* This row is already open - close it */
                this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
                oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            }
            else {
                /* Open this row */
                var rowIndex = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(nTds).closest('tr')[0] ); 
                var detailsRowData = newRowData[rowIndex].details;

                this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
                oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, detailsTableHtml), 'details');
                oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "aaData": detailsRowData,
                    "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": "name" },
                    { "mDataProp": "team" },
                    { "mDataProp": "server" }
                ],
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sInfo": "_TOTAL_ entries"
                    }
                });
                iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Excellent !! That what i was searching allover the internet for. Thanks

Comment: @headwinds Do you have any idea about [How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991927/how-to-create-jquery-datatable-drill-down-rows) Thanks in advance...

Comment: @ClintEastwood I took a brief look at your thread - seems you're getting some excellent help ;-D I would encourage you to attempt to build a fiddle or codepen and then share your experiment even if its a bit broken

Comment: @headwinds I received helps after asking you for help :) Thanks a lot...

Comment: @ClintEastwood great! you should consider adding your example (codepen or fiddle) to this thread to help the next guy

Comment: @headwinds You are right, but I already give a link to that issue in my previous comments. Anyone who need help might use it. Regards...

Answer (score 6):

My version of the nested datatables from @Rafael and @Headwinds but with Datatables version 1.10.11 with new API. Also uses bootstrap. Picks best of both.

See [Nested Datatables 1.10.11](https://jsfiddle.net/karlnicholas/2gc3r7vv/) .

```
 $('#opiniondt tbody td.details-control').on('click', function () {
     var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
     var row = table.row( tr );   

     if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
         //  This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
     }
     else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(iTableCounter) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        // try datatable stuff
        oInnerTable = $('#opiniondt_' + iTableCounter).dataTable({
            data: sections, 
            autoWidth: true, 
            deferRender: true, 
            info: false, 
            lengthChange: false, 
            ordering: false, 
            paging: false, 
            scrollX: false, 
            scrollY: false, 
            searching: false, 
            columns:[ 
               { data:'refCount' },
               { data:'section.codeRange.sNumber.sectionNumber' }, 
               { data:'section.title' }
             ]
        });
        iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, your example was exactly what I needed. I appreciate you updating this question with your code.

Comment: @Nicholas Do you have any idea about [How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991927/how-to-create-jquery-datatable-drill-down-rows). Thanks in advance...

Comment: When I implemented this, there was an issue with this event firing twice (toggling open then closed) after going a different page of my main result set. I fixed it by changing the `$('#opiniondt tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function (){}` to `$('#opiniondt tbody td.details-control').on('click', function (){}`

Comment: Also, you don't need the iTableCounter if you use the rowIndex. `oInnerTable = $('#opiniondt_' + row[0][0])`

Comment: Your example just works like charm, But i have a little query, how can I get the row data from inner table ?

Comment: If you use the 'buttons' plugin and export your dataTable with the nested tables, are the nested tables exported?

Answer (score 2):

I also needed something similar to this, and below a sample how I did. Might help someone.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('tr.tree-toggler').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('tr').eq(2).find('td.tree').toggle(300);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <table>
                    <tbody>

                    <tr class="tree-toggler nav-header">
                        <td>
                            <table border="1" style="width: 100%">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="tree-toggler nav-header">
                                        <td style="width: 30px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 200px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="nav nav-list tree" style="display: none;">
                            <table class="table" border="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 30px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 200px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 30px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 200px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>        
            <table>
                    <tbody>

                    <tr class="tree-toggler nav-header">
                        <td>
                            <table border="1" style="width: 100%">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="tree-toggler nav-header">
                                        <td style="width: 30px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 200px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="nav nav-list tree" style="display: none;">
                            <table class="table" border="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 30px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 200px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 30px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 200px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 30px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 200px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                                            Demo
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example (based on Nicholas' above) where the child datatable uses an ajax call to get info from database.
Note BuildBoMDataTable() builds the parent table, while BuildBoMPartsDataTable() handles each child table.

```
var iTableCounter = 1;
var oInnerTable;
var boMDataTable = new Object;

$(document).ready(function () {
    BuildBoMDataTable();
    AddBomDataTableListener();
});

function AddBomDataTableListener() {

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#boMDataTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = boMDataTable.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Add the html table shell of the datatable.
            row.child(formatBomDataTableDetailRow(iTableCounter)).show();

            //show the datatable row.
            tr.addClass('shown');

            // try datatable stuff
            BuildBoMPartsDataTable(row.data(), iTableCounter);
            iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
        }
    });
}

function BuildBoMDataTable() {

    if ($.isEmptyObject(boMDataTable)) {
        boMDataTable = $("#boMDataTable").DataTable({
            lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
            pageLength: 10,
            dom: "tip",
            pagingType: "simple",
            serverSide: true,
            autowidth: false,
            language: {
                emptyTable: "You have no bill of materials associated with your groups and/or projects."
            },
            ajax: {
                url: "/remote/GetParentTableData",
                type: "POST",
                data: function (d) {
                    var searchData =
                        {
                            personID: $("#PersonID").val(),
                            selecttype: $("#SelectType").val(),
                            draw: d.draw,
                            length: d.length,
                            start: d.start,
                            order: d.order,
                            columns: d.columns,
                            orderbyfield: d.columns[d.order[0].column].data
                        };
                    d.sData = JSON.stringify(searchData);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    className: 'details-control',
                    orderable: false,
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<img class="details-control-mouseover" src="/Content/images/details_transparent_background.png" title="Click to see included parts." alt="Click to see included parts."/>'
                },
                { data: "RecordSelector", orderable: false, class: 'dt-center', width: "6%" },
                { data: "Description", width: "25%" },
                { data: "TeamDetails", width: "25%" },
                { data: "CustomerGroupName", width: "13%" },
                { data: "ProjectGroupName", width: "13%" },
                { data: "ClassificationTypeDescription", width: "10%" },
                { data: "AuditDateFormatted", name: "AuditDateFormatted", className: 'dt-center', width: "10%" }
            ],
            order: [[2, "asc"]]
        });
    }
}

function BuildBoMPartsDataTable(parentObjData, tableCounter) {
    oInnerTable = $("#boMPartDataTable_" + tableCounter).DataTable({
        autoWidth: true,
        dom: "tip",
        pagingType: "simple",
        serverSide: true,
        //processing: true,
        autowidth: false,
        language: {
            emptyTable: "This bill of material contains no part."
        },
        ajax:
        {
            url: "/remote/GetChildTableData",
            type: "POST",
            data: function (d) {
                var searchData =
                    {
                        bomID: parentObjData.BomID,
                        draw: d.draw,
                        length: d.length,
                        start: d.start,
                        order: d.order,
                        columns: d.columns,
                        orderbyfield: d.columns[d.order[0].column].data
                    };
                d.sData = JSON.stringify(searchData);
            }
        },
        columns: [
           { data: 'RecordSelector' },
           { data: 'PartNumber' },
           { data: 'Quantity' },
           { data: 'UomAbbreviation' },
           { data: 'StatusName' },
           { data: 'PartNotes' },
           { data: 'IsBomDescription' }
        ]
    });
}

function formatBomDataTableDetailRow(table_id) {
    return  '<div class="table-responsive">' +
            '    <table id="boMPartDataTable_' + table_id + '" class="table table-striped table-bordered">' +
            '        <thead>' +
            '            <tr>' +
            '                <th></th>' +
            '                <th title="Click to sort by part number." alt="Click to sort by part number.">PartNumber</th>' +
            '                <th title="Click to sort by quantity." alt="Click to sort by quantity.">Quantity</th>' +
            '                <th title="Click to sort by unit of measurement." alt="Click to sort by unit of measurement.">UoM</th>' +
            '                <th title="Click to sort by status name." alt="Click to sort by status name.">Status Name</th>' +
            '                <th title="Click to sort by part notes." alt="Click to sort by part notes.">Part Notes</th>' +
            '                <th title="Click to sort by BoM indicator." alt="Click to sort by BoM indicator.">Is BoM</th>' +
            '            </tr>' +
            '        </thead>' +
            '        <tbody></tbody>' +
            '    </table>' +
            '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post some days ago*: 
-- seems like the example has a 'minor bug', occurring when "iTableCounter > newRowData.length": the implication is that the table 'stops expanding and contracting' on mouse-clicks.

Suggested solution: resetting the counter to '0'.
-- if anyone would be able to refute/verify my suggestions (as JavaScript is not my language of experience), I would be more than grateful! ;)

---

(* If my post is a year too late, I apologize. However, given the great functionality which the example illustrates, I hope I'll be forgiven.)

---

Ole Kristian Ekseth, 
NTNU, Norway