# get nested table row data in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working on data tables, and i need to create a nested table on button click. I have done this so far but unable to get the nested data table row data.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841486/datatables-drill-down-rows-with-nested-independent-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) example. This is what i have done so far to get the row data.

```
oInnerTable = $('#opiniondt_' + iTableCounter).dataTable({
        data: newArr, 
        autoWidth: true, 
        deferRender: true, 
        info: false, 
        lengthChange: false, 
        ordering: false, 
        paging: false, 
        scrollX: false, 
        scrollY: false, 
        searching: false, 
        columns: [
            {   
                className:      'inner-details-control',
                orderable:      false,
                data:           null,
                defaultContent: '' 
            },
            {"mData": "datasetId"}, 
            {"mData": "name"},
            {"mData": "datasetType", "visible": false},
            {"mData": "parentDatasetID", "visible": false},
            {"mData": "description", "visible": false},
            {"mData": "totalRecords"},
            {"mData": "creationTimeStr"},
            {"mData": "endTimeStr"},
            {bSortable: false,
                mRender: function (o) {return '<button class="btn btn-blue innerDatasetDetailButton" id="innerDatasetDetailButton"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>'; }
            }
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']]
    });

$('#opiniondt_' + iTableCounter + ' tbody').unbind().on("click", "td.inner-details-control", function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = oInnerTable.row( tr );
        var rowData = oInnerTable.row( tr ).data();  
        iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            //createInnerTable(tr, row, rowData);
        }
   });
```

I have initialized the inner table with `oInnerTable` but it gives me error on `oInnerTable`

> TypeError: oInnerTable.row is not a function

Can Any one tell me how can i get row data from nested data table ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `('#opiniondt_' + iTableCounter).DataTable(...)` when you initialise the table - note the difference in case. If you use `dataTable(...)`, you get a jQuery object back in `oInnerTable`, and not the DataTables API object that you need to issue the `row()` command.

Comment: ok, But my question was How can I get row data from inner table ? this solution doesn't solve my problem

Comment: You're getting the row data already with the `var rowData = oInnerTable.row( tr ).data();` statement, it was failing with that error because you didn't have the DataTables' API handle, just a jQuery one.

Comment: I have solved the issue by using another way of datatable APi : `var row = $('#opiniondt_' + iTableCounter).dataTable().api().row( tr );`

Comment: Yep, that gets the DataTables handle too, both valid! :)