# How to show nested row inside JQuery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

> I am calling one API from my asp net-core application which is
> returning me following Json data.
> Inside this Json **companyRegionList** is dynamic if there is no data inside it then we will get it's Value **null** .

```
"result":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "stateName":"Ow",
         "regionDirector":"Cassy Fusset",
         "status" : Active,
         "phoneNumber":"123456",
         "email":"cassy.f@gmail.com",
         "companyRegionList":{
            "companyList":[
               {
                  "companyId":4,
                  "code":"ATL",
                  "Name":"Atlanta",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"123456",
                  "Status":"Active"
               },
               {
                  "companyId":4,
                  "code":"ATL",
                  "Name":"Atlanta",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"123456",
                  "Status":"Active"
               },
               {
                  "companyId":4,
                  "code":"ATL",
                  "Name":"Atlanta",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"123456",
                  "Status":"Active"
               },
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "stateName":"Florida",
         "regionDirector":"Boone Williams",
         "status" : Active,
         "phoneNumber":"123456",
         "email":"Boone.w@gmail.com",
         "companyRegionList":
         "companyList":[{
                  "companyId":4,
                  "code":"ATL",
                  "Name":"Atlanta",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"123456",
                  "Status":"Active"
               }
      },    ]
      {
         "id":1,
         "stateName":"NW Georgia",
         "regionDirector":"Mikel Stapp",
         "status" : Active,
         "phoneNumber":"123456",
         "email":"mikel.s@gmail@gmail.com",
         "companyRegionList": null
      }
   ]
```

[I want to Show my Json Data to this way using Jquery Datatable. if CompanyRegionList inside json data is null then i want to show **No data available** .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyClG.png)

Comment: Hope this link may help,.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841486/datatables-drill-down-rows-with-nested-independent-table

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/zz3cH/

Comment: Can you  please help me to make a code For this jSon  data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
var result = [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "stateName": "Ow",
         "regionDirector": "Cassy Fusset",
         "status": "Active",
         "phoneNumber": "(987)767 67678",
         "email": "cassy.f@gmail.com",
         "companyRegionList": {
            "companyList": [
               {
                  "companyId": 1,
                  "code":"ATL",
                  "Name":"Atlanta",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"(336) 876 9874",
                  "Status":"Active"
               },
               {
                  "companyId": 2,
                  "code":"ATL2",
                  "Name":"Atlanta  II",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"(336) 876 9874",
                  "Status":"Active"
               },
               {
                  "companyId": 3,
                  "code":"ATL",
                  "Name":"Atlanta Pinnacle",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"(336) 876 9874",
                  "Status":"Active"
               },
               {
                  "companyId": 4,
                  "code":"BDC",
                  "Name":"BDC Staff",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"(336) 876 9874",
                  "Status":"Active"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "stateName":"Florida",
         "regionDirector":"Boone Williams",
         "status": "Active",
         "phoneNumber":"(987)767 67678",
         "email":"Boone.w@gmail.com",
         "companyRegionList": {
                "companyList": [
                     {
                  "companyId":4,
                  "code":"ATL",
                  "Name":"Atlanta",
                  "Director":"corey Cullen ",
                  "contact":"123456",
                  "Status":"Active"
               }
                ]
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 3,
         "stateName":"NW Georgia",
         "regionDirector":"Mikel Stapp",
         "status": "Active",
         "phoneNumber":"(987)767 67678",
         "email":"mikel.s@gmail@gmail.com",
         "companyRegionList": null
      }
   ];

function format ( d ) {

    // `d` is the original data object for the row
     var html = '<table class="table">'+
        '<thead><tr style="background-color: #f5f8fb;">'+
            '<th>CITY CODE</th>'+
            '<th>CITY NAME</th>'+
            '<th>DIRECTOR</th>'+
            '<th>CONTACT</th>'+
            '<th>STATUS</th>'+
        '</tr></thead><tbody>';
      
        if(d.companyRegionList == null)
             html += '<tr><td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">No data available</td></tr>';
        else {
            for (let i in d.companyRegionList.companyList) {
        
               html += '<tr><td>' + d.companyRegionList.companyList[i].code + '</td>';
               html += '<td>' + d.companyRegionList.companyList[i].Name + '</td>';
               html += '<td>' + d.companyRegionList.companyList[i].Director + '</td>';
               html += '<td>' + d.companyRegionList.companyList[i].contact + '</td>';
               html += '<td>' + d.companyRegionList.companyList[i].Status + '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
        
    html += '</tbody</table>';
    
    return html;
}

var oTable = $('#tblExample').DataTable({
  ordering: false,
  paging: false,
  searching: true,
  info: false,
  data: result,
  columns: [
      { data: 'id', visible: false },
      { data: 'stateName', className: 'textUC' },
      { data: 'regionDirector', className: 'textUC' },
      { data: 'status', className: 'textUC' },
      { data: 'phoneNumber', className: 'textUC' },
      { data: 'email', className: 'textUC' },
      {
        "className":      'details-control',
        "orderable":      false,
        "data":           null,
        "defaultContent": ''
      }
  ]
});

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#tblExample tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

  $('#tblExample tbody > tr').addClass('rowInactive');
  
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = oTable.row( tr );
  $(tr).removeClass('rowInactive');

  if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
    $('#tblExample tbody > tr').removeClass('rowInactive');
  }
  else {
    // Open this row
    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/I8lvlcC.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    /*background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;*/
    cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://imgur.com/wUcJYSG.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    /*background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;*/
}

.textUC {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rowActive {
  color: black;
}

.rowInactive {
  color: #97aaba;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="tblExample" class="table" style="width: 100%">
    <!--<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>stateName</th>
        <th>regionDirector</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>phoneNumber</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>-->
  </table>
```

Comment: I want to show it on Full width of page @Sagnalrac .

Comment: Why this function format(d) is used and also why columns.data property is null ?

Comment: @Coder: regarding the full width, have you tried adding `style="width: 100%"` to your table?

About your second question, actually you can name that function whatever you want, I only followed the example that you can find in the **jQuery DataTable's web site** documentation: **[Child rows (show extra / detailed information)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)**

Comment: @Coder: By the way, regarding your third question, there would be occasions where you'll need an extra column in your DataTable but not precisely to show data (from server-side response). For example, imagine that you want to include the **Edit**, **Delete** and **Details** actions (either with links or with icons), or like in your case, an image to expand/collapse the child rows. In those cases you can put `data: null`because you don't need to show data in that column. Although I haven't tried to omit that parameter and see what happens.

Comment: @Coder: After a further research now I can explain you better when to use `data: null` in a column. This action has effects on two other initialization options:

- `defaultContent` property: When null is given as the data option and defaultContent is specified for the column, the value defined by defaultContent will be used for the cell.

- `render` property: When null is used for the data option and the render option is specified for the column, the whole data source for the row is used for the renderer.

More info [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data)

Comment: while i am performing search operation this gives me error .

Comment: @Coder: I'm not sure what's happening on your side. I edited my answer to enable **Searching** functionality in my example and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes it was my Mistake Now it's Working Fine.

Comment: I only want to show row after searching if it contains nested row or else I will not show that parent row after searching How can i do this ?